# How to limit text log size done with TraceSource in ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I'm using [this example](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/10/22/configuring-simple-tracesource-for-logging-purposes) to implement a simple text logging for my ASP.NET web application written in C#. It works fine, except that I don't know how to limit the log file from growing uncontrollably. Say, if I want the log file to override old records after say, 1000 records, or if the file becomes larger than N megabytes in size. How do I do that with `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener`?